# Iterate through cells in different worksheets to parse a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets: one has a column (yes/no) and the second is a list of people. If the user's last name on Sheet 2 is also on Sheet 1, I want to mark that column 'Yes'. Is there a way to script this? Ideally I would want to do this:

- Iterate through a row on Sheet 1.
- If a last name in that row matches the name on Sheet 2, then mark the column cell as 'Yes'

Comment: If you showed us some sample of data, it would be easier. Yet, you can have a web search about using a `VLOOKUP` formula

Comment: Yes we need to see samples of the names, is it "Joe Bloggs" or "Bloggs Joe" or "Bloggs, Joe" etc....  How do you distinguish between first and last names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is to use worksheet functions instead of resorting to VBA. In the 'Yes/No' column enter the following formula and fill down.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,0)),"No","Yes")
```

Here `A1` is the name from Sheet2 you are looking for, and `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5` is the list of names on Sheet1 you want to look through.

**EDIT :**

If you want to match only first word of the list on Sheet1, you can still do this using an array formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,LEFT(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,FIND(" ",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5)-1),0)),"No","Yes")
```

Enter this as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter. The formula should be shown inside {...} in the formula bar.

If your list of names are of the form "Last First" this will work. If instead, the names are of the form "Last, First", then you can use the following instead.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,LEFT(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,FIND(", ",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5)-1),0)),"No","Yes")
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that I want to parse names (only the first word of a string) so I think I needed to resort to VBA.

Comment: +1 Once Dave's lets us know how to distinguish between first and last names, I'm sure the formula can be adjusted to suit.

Comment: Yes, please let us know how the names are formatted on each sheet.

Comment: Sorry for the delay ... all names are Last, First but for my purposes I want to grab last names only (everything before the comma).

Comment: So the names on sheet2 are in the format "Last, First" correct?  And what about the names on sheet1 are they just a list of last names?  If so try =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,0)),"No","Yes")